# How to render your own HTML page in zaproxy while analyzing an incoming request

Tags: java, html, http, zap

We are developing a new extension for Zaproxy (in the specific [zap-extensions](https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions) repo), which checks incoming requests and shows an HTML page if for example a 'bad' password has been detected (assume the user fills it in a non-hashed password field). In that HTML page, the user is being asked whether or not he wants to proceed.

We are wondering how we can easily visualize our webpage in the browser, given that we work in zap-extensions. We figured out that it is possible by sending a request to for example google.com, after which we change the whole body to our HTML page. We do, however, realize that it is not an ideal solution.

Are there easier solutions, where a new incoming response is spawn on demand in the method onHttpRequestSend(HttpMessage msg) (The extension resembles 'frontendscanner')?

Answer (score 1):

Asked (and being answered) on the ZAP Developer Group: https://groups.google.com/g/zaproxy-develop/c/PpRnZShw6NQ/m/RvauU6koBAAJ